# Problems with update/upgrade Ubuntu 20.10 on Raspberry pi 4 with SSD

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 8GB with Kingston SSD of 240 GB and I installed Ubuntu 20.10 on it with Berryboot. Everything seems to be fine but when I try to do an update and upgrade on terminal I get this error:

```
Setting up flash-kernel (3.103ubuntu1~20.10.1) ...
flash-kernel: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up u-boot-rpi:arm64 (2020.10+dfsg-1ubuntu0~20.10.1) ...
Error: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
dpkg: error processing package u-boot-rpi:arm64 (--configure):
 installed u-boot-rpi:arm64 package post-installation script subprocess returned
 error exit status 1
Processing triggers for flash-kernel (3.103ubuntu1~20.10.1) ...
Can't find /boot/vmlinuz- (see /tmp/flash-kernel-no-kernel-error.log)
dpkg: error processing package flash-kernel (--configure):
 installed flash-kernel package post-installation script subprocess returned err
or exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 u-boot-rpi:arm64
 flash-kernel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

With this I also can't download any programs.

I'm searching the web for days now and still couldn't fix this.

Who knows what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious why you're using Ubuntu instead of Raspberry Pi OS.  I realise they aren't the same, but I thought the latter would be easier to get working.  Especially if you've been stuck on it for days...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you, and to my horror this was the only similar issue I could find (with no helpful answers).

Eventually I searched the line `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` which led me to the below guide that indicated that this error indicates package damage:

https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/

Eventually I just removed the packages:

```
sudo apt remove flash-kernel
sudo apt remove u-boot-rpi:arm64
```

This successfully freed my apt command and let me install Dillo:

```
sudo apt install dillo
```

I'm not sure if there will be any side effects, but if there are I'm canning Berryboot and just flashing Ubuntu directly to my SD. I've had way to many problems in the past 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The essential part of the error message is this line:

```
Error: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
```

This indicates that the SD Card's first partition is not mounted at `/boot/firmware`. A standard installation has a line such as

```
LABEL=system-boot       /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults        0       1
```

in the `/etc/fstab` file. If that line is missing, or if there is something wrong with the SD Card itself, or if no SD Card is present, you will get the error above.

The dpkg failure is telling you that apt could not finish its job, and you may end up with an unbootable system if you do not fix the underlying issue.